# Why do I have to import a library twice in Python (IDLE and the imported file)?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am running Python 3.7.6 shell and have the library numpy installed correctly.

In my shell I type:

```
import numpy as np
```

and can use numpy however I desire. I then proceed to import 'my_lib.py' which contains:

```
def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=0)
```

In my shell I can call the function softmax(x) but I immediately get the error

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

My hypothesis here would be I've imported numpy into 'shell scope' and i've also imported softmax(x) into 'shell scope' so everything should be happy. To fix this problem I have to add

```
import numpy as np
```

into 'my_lib.py'.

**How come I have to import numpy twice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in each module can only use identifiers (names) that have be defined in or imported into that module.  The global dict in each module only contains names global to that module.  It might better be called the module dict or modular dict, but the name goes back to when there were no modules in computing.

You might benefit from reading https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html and probably elsewhere in the tutorial.

(None of this has anything to do with the editor you use to write code or the IDE or shell you use to pass code to Python.)

Comment: So it’s by design? Is that because each module is just referencing a single location of numpy? It’s not actually going out to grab it’s own copy is it?

Comment: Yes, No.  In each module that does 'import numpy', the name 'numpy' is bound to sys.modules['numpy'].  That is the 'single location' of an in-memory compiled, ready-to-use, numpy module.